# CSS `contain-intrinsic-size` causes jitter

Tags: css

I have a large tabular (not an actual `<table>`) list to display. I applied `contain-intrinsic-size` and `content-visibility:auto` to each row to speed up rendering, which worked. Render time went from ~2000ms to ~200. Great.

The bad news is sometimes it causes the content to jump back and forth very quickly. Much faster than my screencap shows. The jittering goes on forever until you scroll again. Though that can also just cause a fresh round of jitter.

[image: Animation showing viewport starting at top, the user hitting end, and then the screen jittering up and down]

#### Question

How can I use `contain-intrinsic-size`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs when some elements are smaller than the value for `contain-intrinsic-size`. When contain-intrinsic-size is smaller than all of the elements, the error does not occur.